# Best solution for unit-testing Mootools code

Tags: javascript, jquery, unit-testing, mootools

I want to find the best solution for testing Mootools code. I have wide expirience in jQuery and it wasn't hard to find tool for testing jQuery code - QUnit. Is there any equiv tool for unit-testing Mootools code?

Answer (score 2):

See [JSSpec](http://code.google.com/p/jsspec/) or [Jasmine](https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine/wiki).

Comment: sinon + js test driver is ok.